# Force element width to match exactly parent width and not screen width

Tags: css, width

In the snippet below you can see that the green `.bottom` stops at the width of the screen using a width of 100%. Can I force the width to match exactly the parent width? In this case 1000px.
The problem is that the red `.top` is a variable width so setting a fixed width for the green `.bottom` is not an option.

```css
.parent {
  width: 700px;
}

div.container {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
}

div.top {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  width: 1000px;
}

div.bottom {
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Percentage is relative to it's parent. Viewport width however is relative to the viewport (`vw`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS grid instead of flexbox:

```css
.parent {
  width: 700px;
}

div.container {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  align-content: start; /* don't forget this */
  height: 100px;
}

div.top {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  width: 1000px;
}

div.bottom {
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```